# How to use terraform to deploy to private hardware

Tags: terraform

I have been searching through documentation and (a lof of) marketing related material and I'm quite convinced that Terraform is a handy tool to deploy things to AWS et al. But I have not seen an example (yet) on how to use it to deploy something to my own virtual server. Is that even possible and if so, can somebody point me to the right documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform is pretty cloud-oriented; you might look through its [list of providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html) and see what's there that's relevant to you.  If internally you're actually running VMware vSphere, there's [a Terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/index.html) for that which can provision VMs, but otherwise the thing it would want to shortcut is "buy a server and rack it up".

Also note that Terraform's strengths are much more around requesting prepackaged cloud things (I'm most familiar with AWS, and there you can get EC2 instances [VMs] and managed hosted relational databases) and much less around configuring them.  Once you've gotten a VM of some sort, you can run individual shell commands against it, but usually the best thing to do is to use Terraform to invoke some other system-management tool (Ansible, Salt Stack, Chef, ...).

Comment: I looked through the list but did not find any "use your own cloud"-provider, or something similar. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

For "private cloud" there are [terraform providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html) for VMWare, OpenStack, and Azure Stack.